# Do the changes to cpumask using sched_setaffinity() take place immediately

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, affinity

I am writing a linux kernel module that needs to pin two threads on two different cpus. I am planning to use sched_setaffinity() after exporting it in the kernel. Is there any other exported function for the same ?

Also, if I set only 1 CPU in the cpumask, will the thread be moved to that cpu with immediate effect ? If not, how do I enforce the same ? Will it help to call schedule() just after sched_setaffinity() ?

Comment: does this help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766395/how-does-sched-setaffinity-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `sched_setaffinity` says

> If the process specified by `pid` is not currently running on one of the CPUs  specified  in  `mask`,  then  that process is migrated to one of the CPUs specified in `mask`.

My intepretation is that this migration happens immediately, before the call to `sched_setaffinity` has returned.