# setting processor affinity with C++ that will run on Linux

Tags: c++, process, processor, affinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CPU Affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280909/cpu-affinity)

I'm running on Linux and I want to write a C++ program that will set 2 specific processors that my 2 applications that will run in parallel (i.e. setting each process to run on a different core/CPU). I want to use processor affinity tool with C++. Please can anyone help with C++ code.

Comment: Have you read the manpages for `sched_setaffinity` and `pthread_setaffinity_np` (and also `taskset` to do it from the command line)? If so, could you describe the problems you're having?

Answer (score 10):

From the command line you can use [taskset(1)](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html), or from within your code you can use [sched_setaffinity(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity).

E.g.

```
#ifdef __linux__    // Linux only
#include <sched.h>  // sched_setaffinity
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef __linux__
    int cpuAffinity = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : -1;

    if (cpuAffinity > -1)
    {
        cpu_set_t mask;
        int status;

        CPU_ZERO(&mask);
        CPU_SET(cpuAffinity, &mask);
        status = sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask);
        if (status != 0)
        {
            perror("sched_setaffinity");
        }
    }
#endif

    // ... your program ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, I want to auto run with C++ instead of going through command line. I am not too sure of how to use int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize,
  cpu_set_t *mask);
int sched_getaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t cpusetsize,
  cpu_set_t *mask); please do you have run C++ code, that I can test with?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity) or [pthread_setaffinity_np](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766395/how-does-sched-setaffinity-work)