# How to find out the number of CPUs using python

Tags: python, system-information

I want to know the number of CPUs on the local machine using Python. The result should be `user/real` as output by `time(1)` when called with an optimally scaling userspace-only program.

Comment: You should keep cpusets (in Linux) in mind. If you're in a cpuset, the solutions below will still give the number of real CPUs in the system, not the number available to your process. `/proc/<PID>/status` has some lines that tell you the number of CPUs in the current cpuset: look for `Cpus_allowed_list`.

Comment: if you are using torch you can do ```import torch.multiprocessing; mp.cpu_count()```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

If you're interested into the number of processors *available* to your current process, you have to check [cpuset](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html) first. Otherwise (or if cpuset is not in use), [`multiprocessing.cpu_count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) is the way to go in Python 2.6 and newer. The following method falls back to a couple of alternative methods in older versions of Python:

```
import os
import re
import subprocess


def available_cpu_count():
    """ Number of available virtual or physical CPUs on this system, i.e.
    user/real as output by time(1) when called with an optimally scaling
    userspace-only program"""

    # cpuset
    # cpuset may restrict the number of *available* processors
    try:
        m = re.search(r'(?m)^Cpus_allowed:\s*(.*)$',
                      open('/proc/self/status').read())
        if m:
            res = bin(int(m.group(1).replace(',', ''), 16)).count('1')
            if res > 0:
                return res
    except IOError:
        pass

    # Python 2.6+
    try:
        import multiprocessing
        return multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    except (ImportError, NotImplementedError):
        pass

    # https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil
    try:
        import psutil
        return psutil.cpu_count()   # psutil.NUM_CPUS on old versions
    except (ImportError, AttributeError):
        pass

    # POSIX
    try:
        res = int(os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN'))

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        pass

    # Windows
    try:
        res = int(os.environ['NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS'])

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        pass

    # jython
    try:
        from java.lang import Runtime
        runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
        res = runtime.availableProcessors()
        if res > 0:
            return res
    except ImportError:
        pass

    # BSD
    try:
        sysctl = subprocess.Popen(['sysctl', '-n', 'hw.ncpu'],
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        scStdout = sysctl.communicate()[0]
        res = int(scStdout)

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except (OSError, ValueError):
        pass

    # Linux
    try:
        res = open('/proc/cpuinfo').read().count('processor\t:')

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except IOError:
        pass

    # Solaris
    try:
        pseudoDevices = os.listdir('/devices/pseudo/')
        res = 0
        for pd in pseudoDevices:
            if re.match(r'^cpuid@[0-9]+$', pd):
                res += 1

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except OSError:
        pass

    # Other UNIXes (heuristic)
    try:
        try:
            dmesg = open('/var/run/dmesg.boot').read()
        except IOError:
            dmesgProcess = subprocess.Popen(['dmesg'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            dmesg = dmesgProcess.communicate()[0]

        res = 0
        while '\ncpu' + str(res) + ':' in dmesg:
            res += 1

        if res > 0:
            return res
    except OSError:
        pass

    raise Exception('Can not determine number of CPUs on this system')
```

Comment: On a MacPro 1,0 running the latest Ubuntu, on an HP Laptop running a recent Debian, and on an old eMachine running an old Ubuntu, the cpus_allowed results of `/proc/self/status` are respectively ff, f and f--- corresponding to 8, 4 and 4 by your (correct) math. However the actual numbers of CPUs are respectively 4, 2 and 1. I find that counting the number of occurrences of the word "processor" in `/proc/cpuinfo` may be the better way to go. (Or do I have the question wrong?)

Comment: With some further research--- if that  can be said of "Googling"--- I find from the use of `/proc/cpuinfo` that if for any one of the listings for each "processor" you multiply the "siblings" by the "cpu cores" you get your "Cpus_allowed" number. And I gather that the siblings refer to hyper-threading, hence your reference to "virtual". But the fact remains that your "Cpus_allowed" number is 8 on my MacPro whereas your `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` answer is 4. My own `open('/proc/cpuinfo').read().count('processor')` also produces 4, the number of physical cores (two dual-core processors).

Comment: `open('/proc/self/status').read()` forgets to close the file. Use `with open('/proc/self/status') as f: f.read()` instead

Comment: `os.cpu_count()`

Comment: @timdiels Not entirely correct; when the file handle's refcount reaches zero (immediately after the `read`), the GC will clean it up by calling (in latest versions) `io.BufferedReader.__del__`, which closes first: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/_pyio.py#L375-L385

Comment: @amcgregor That's pretty cool and unless you have a circular reference you don't even have to wait for `gc.collect()`

Comment: @amcgregor Actually, reference counting is an implementation detail of CPython and thus should not be relied on (when easily avoidable as in this case) according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/7396043/1031434

Comment: @timdiels Certainly is an artifact of the interpreter implementation, though I have not seen evidence in the question as to which interpreter is being used.  Under Pypy, cleanup (call to `__del__`) will happen ["at some point in the future after the last reference is freed, or not if the interpreter is shut down beforehand"](https://pypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies).  The "or not" situation is also acceptable; when the process is shut down, file handles are closed anyway.

Comment: @amcgregor In this case it's acceptable, agreed, just file handles being left open which I guess is ok if you're not writing a long running daemon/process; which I fear might end up hitting a max open file handles of the OS. It's worse when writing to a file that needs to get read again before the process ends, but that's not the case here so that's a moot point. Still a good idea to have a habit of using `with` for when you do encounter a case where you need it.

Comment: This seems to have been added to Python 3 as `os.sched_getaffinity`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python/55423170#55423170

Comment: It should be noted os.sched_getaffinity does not seem to be available on Windows.

Comment: The reply should clarify that the count is the logical count has already mentioned in other comments. As of now (python 3.7) psutil.cpu_count(logical=False) is the only way I know to get the number of physical cores as suggested by @davoud-taghawi-nejad.

Answer (score 1270):

If you have python with a version >= 2.6 you can simply use

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

Comment: multiprocessing is also supported in 3.x

Comment: I want to add that this doesn't work in IronPython which raises a NotImplementedError.

Comment: This gives the number of CPUs on available... not in use by the program!

Comment: On Python 3.6.2 I could only use `os.cpu_count()`

Comment: is there a way to know only the number allocated (for example using slurm)

Comment: python -c 'import multiprocessing as m; print(m.cpu_count())'

Comment: Also, as noted below, this count can include "virtual" hyperthreaded cpus, which may not be what you want if you are scheduling cpu-intensive tasks.

Comment: Fun fact, both these calls report "4" on my apple computer that _definitely_ has only 2 cores. (1 dual-core cpu)

Comment: @SamyBencherif Can you share more information on your CPU?

Comment: @SamyBencherif this is a result of what was mentioned above.  "Hyperthreading" results in the OS seeing double the number of physical processor cores

Comment: Besides the hyperthreaded cpus, `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` does not account for limits in cpu usage through `docker run --cpus=2`.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. It will not work with Docker. For example `docker run -it --rm --cpuset-cpus=0,1 python:3 python3 -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())"`.

Answer (score 160):

**`len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))` is what you usually want**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_getaffinity

`os.sched_getaffinity(0)` (added in Python 3) returns the set of CPUs available considering the [`sched_setaffinity` Linux system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490756/how-to-use-sched-getaffinity-and-sched-setaffinity-in-linux-from-c/50117787#50117787), which limits which CPUs a process and its children can run on.

`0` means to get the value for the current process. The function returns a `set()` of allowed CPUs, thus the need for `len()`.

`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` and `os.cpu_count()` on the other hand just returns the total number of logical CPUs, that is e.g. the number of [CPUs considering hyperthreading](https://superuser.com/questions/133082/what-is-the-difference-between-hyper-threading-and-multiple-cores).

The difference is especially important because certain cluster management systems such as [Platform LSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) limit job CPU usage with `sched_getaffinity`.

Therefore, if you use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, your script might try to use way more cores than it has available, which may lead to overload and timeouts.

We can see the difference concretely by restricting the affinity with the `taskset` utility, which allows us to control the affinity of a process.

**Minimal `taskset` example**

For example, if I restrict Python to just 1 core (core 0) in my 16 core system:

```
taskset -c 0 ./main.py
```

with the test script:

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import os

print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
print(os.cpu_count())
print(len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)))
```

then the output is:

```
16
16
1
```

**Vs `nproc`**

`nproc` does respect the affinity by default and:

```
taskset -c 0 nproc
```

outputs:

```
1
```

and `man nproc` makes that quite explicit:

> print the number of processing units available

Therefore, `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))` behaves like `nproc` by default.

`nproc` has the `--all` flag for the less common case that you want to get the physical CPU count without considering taskset:

```
taskset -c 0 nproc --all
```

**`os.cpu_count` documentation**

The documentation of `os.cpu_count` also briefly mentions this https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.cpu_count

> This number is not equivalent to the number of CPUs the current process can use. The number of usable CPUs can be obtained with `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))`

The same comment is also copied on the documentation of `multiprocessing.cpu_count`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

From the 3.8 source under [`Lib/multiprocessing/context.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L41) we also see that `multiprocessing.cpu_count` just forwards to `os.cpu_count`, except that the `multiprocessing` one throws an exception instead of returning None if `os.cpu_count` fails:

```
    def cpu_count(self):
        '''Returns the number of CPUs in the system'''
        num = os.cpu_count()
        if num is None:
            raise NotImplementedError('cannot determine number of cpus')
        else:
            return num
```

**3.8 availability: systems with a native `sched_getaffinity` function**

The only downside of this `os.sched_getaffinity` is that this appears to be UNIX only as of Python 3.8.

cpython 3.8 seems to just try to compile a small C hello world with a `sched_setaffinity` function call during configuration time, and if not present `HAVE_SCHED_SETAFFINITY` is not set and the function will likely be missing:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/configure#L11523
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Modules/posixmodule.c#L6457

**`psutil.Process().cpu_affinity()`: third-party version with a Windows port**

The third-party [`psutil` package](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) (`pip install psutil`) had been mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840102/895245 but not the `cpu_affinity` function: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity

Usage:

```
import psutil
print(len(psutil.Process().cpu_affinity()))
```

This function does the same as the standard library `os.sched_getaffinity` on Linux, but they have also implemented it for Windows by making a call to the `GetProcessAffinityMask` Windows API function:

- https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/ee60bad610822a7f630c52922b4918e684ba7695/psutil/_psutil_windows.c#L1112
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessaffinitymask

So in other words: those Windows users have to stop being lazy and send a patch to the upstream stdlib :-)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5.2.

**`os.process_cpu_count()` (Python 3.13)**

https://docs.python.org/3.13/library/os.html#os.process_cpu_count

This seems to be the same as `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))`, except that:

- it can be overridden by the `-X cpu_count` Python CLI argumentor the `PYTHON_CPU_COUNT` environment variable
- TODO confirm: it might fall back nicely on platforms where devs were too lazy to implement `sched_getaffinity` rather than blow an exception

Mentioned [by jfs in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python/55423170?noredirect=1#comment137818389_55423170).

Comment: Only available on Unix.

Comment: Works on jupyter notebook!

Comment: Just to clarify, does this support CPU limits in `Docker`-ized containers, as well?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum from a quick read Docker seems to be able to fake `nproc` to match `--cpuset-cpus`, but I haven't tested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871540/how-many-cpus-does-a-docker-container-use/54112066#54112066 Docker can also limit how much time the kernel should allocate to each instance as wel it seems e.g. with `--cpu-quota`, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint so even `nproc` might not be fully meaningful in that case however.

Comment: This solution is also necessary for HPC situations where a compute node might have 48 cores but you only requested 10 of them. os.cpu_count() will tell you there's 48 cores but as @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 says you run into all sorts of problems if you try to use that. os.sched_getaffinity(0) will report what was actually requested from the scheduler eg. PBS

Comment: on macOS: `AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'cpu_affinity'`

Comment: @Anentropic thanks for this info, what a shame. mac users gotta look into `psutil` and upstream to stdlib then as well it seems then :-)

Comment: `"multiprocessing.cpu_count() and os.cpu_count() on the other hand just returns the total number of physical CPUs."` <- both these functions return the number of logical cores: in the case of hyperthreading this will be double the number of physical cores.

Comment: This is not a good method to use inside Jupyter notebooks, which will return a value of only 2, when an ordinary python process might return 96.  when running Jupyter notebooks then, I will typically copy the sched affinity output from a python REPL in a shell, and set it in Jupyter via os.sched_setaffinity(0, {...paste...})

Comment: @sh37211 I don't reproduce on Ubuntu 22.10, `notebook==6.5.3` on a minimal example, the value for `os.sched_getaffinity(0)` inside Jupyter and outside were the same. I wonder why this happens to you.

Comment: Using the `psutil` method on macos also does not work:

`AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute 'cpu_affinity'`

Comment: On WSL, all three functions return the same value for me, corresponding to the number of logical processors.

Comment: On Python 3.13, there is [`os.process_cpu_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.13/library/os.html#os.process_cpu_count). It is like `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))` but can be also overridden by `-X cpu_count=<n>`, `$PYTHON_CPU_COUNT` (both `os.cpu_count()` & `os.process_cpu_count()` are affected).

Comment: @jfs thanks for this. Weird function, feels like stdlib clutter, why not just let users limit CPUs via regular cli parameters.

Answer (score 136):

Another option is to use the [`psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) library, which always turn out useful in these situations:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.cpu_count()
2
```

This should work on any platform supported by `psutil`(Unix and Windows).

Note that in some occasions `multiprocessing.cpu_count` may raise a `NotImplementedError` while `psutil` will be able to obtain the number of CPUs. This is simply because `psutil` first tries to use the same techniques used by `multiprocessing` and, if those fail, it also uses other techniques.

Comment: This one is really good, considering that used method allows to find out is the CPU cores are logical ore physical ones. `psutil.cpu_count(logical = True)`

Comment: Hi @Bakuriu, Is there any way to get the number of cpu cores being used by a specific process using psutil?

Comment: @Devilhunter On Windows on my Intel i7-8700 `psutil.cpu_count()` gives 12 (it's a 6-core CPU with hyperthreading).
This is because the default argument of `logical` is True, so you explicitly need to write `psutil.cpu_count(logical = False)` to get the number of physical Cores.

Comment: `psutil.Process().cpu_affinity()` is what most users will want I believe as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423170/895245 BTW.

Comment: answer needs updation

Comment: psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)

Answer (score 69):

In Python 3.4+: [os.cpu_count()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count).

`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` is implemented in terms of this function but raises `NotImplementedError` if `os.cpu_count()` returns `None` ("can't determine number of CPUs").

Comment: See also the documentation of `cpu_count`. `len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))` might be better, depending on the purpose.

Comment: @Albert yes, the number of CPUs in the system (`os.cpu_count()`—what OP asks) may differ from the number of CPUs that are available to the current process (`os.sched_getaffinity(0)`).

Comment: I know. I just wanted to add that for other readers, who might miss this difference, to get a more complete picture from them.

Comment: Also: the `os.sched_getaffinity(0)` is *not* available on BSD, so the use of `os.cpu_count()` is required (without other external library, that is).

Comment: It should be noted os.sched_getaffinity does not seem to be available on Windows.

Answer (score 63):

If you want to know the number of physical cores (not virtual hyperthreaded cores), here is a platform independent solution:

```py
psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
```

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst

Note that the default value for `logical` is `True`, so if you do want to include hyperthreaded cores you can use:

```py
psutil.cpu_count()
```

This will give the same number as `os.cpu_count()` and `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, neither of which have the `logical` keyword argument.

Comment: What is difference between a logical CPU and not not a logical one?
on my laptop: `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False) #4` `psutil.cpu_count(logical=True) #8` and `multiprocessing.cpu_count() #8`

Comment: @user305883 assuming you have a x86 CPU, you have [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) on this machine, i.e. each physical core corresponds to two hyperthreads ('logical' cores). Hyperthreading allows the physical core to be used to execute instructions from thread B when parts of it are idle for thread A (e.g. waiting for data being fetched from the cache or memory). Depending on your code one can get one or a few tens of percents of additional core utilization but it is far below the performance of a real physical core.

Comment: By far the best answer, but it's very difficult to find among all the others.

Answer (score 32):

These give you the hyperthreaded CPU count

1. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`
2. `os.cpu_count()`

These give you the virtual machine CPU count

1. `psutil.cpu_count()`
2. `numexpr.detect_number_of_cores()`

Only matters if you works on VMs.

Comment: Not really. As noted, `os.cpu_count()` and `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` will return hyperthreaded cpu counts, not the actual physical cpu count.

Comment: Yes. I reworded. It's typically # of cores x 2. What I mean is that if you are on a virtual machine, that carved out 8 cores, but your host machine is 20 core physically, first set of command give you 20, second set of command give you 8.

Answer (score 27):

For python version above 3.4 you can use

```
import os
os.cpu_count()
```

If you are looking for an equivanlent of linux command `nproc`. You have this option

```
len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
```

Answer (score 22):

`multiprocessing.cpu_count()` will return the number of logical CPUs, so if you have a quad-core CPU with hyperthreading, it will return `8`.  If you want the number of physical CPUs, use the python bindings to hwloc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import hwloc
topology = hwloc.Topology()
topology.load()
print topology.get_nbobjs_by_type(hwloc.OBJ_CORE)
```

hwloc is designed to be portable across OSes and architectures.

Comment: In this case, I want the number of logical CPUs (i.e. how many threads should I start if this program scales really well), but the answer may be helpful nonetheless.

Comment: or `psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)`

Answer (score 13):

This may work for those of us who use different os/systems, but want to get the best of all worlds:

```
import os
workers = os.cpu_count()
if 'sched_getaffinity' in dir(os):
    workers = len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use "joblib" for this purpose.

```
import joblib
print joblib.cpu_count()
```

This method will give you the number of cpus in the system. joblib needs to be installed though. More information on joblib can be found here       https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html

Alternatively you can use numexpr package of python. It has lot of simple functions helpful for getting information about the system cpu.

```
import numexpr as ne
print ne.detect_number_of_cores()
```

Comment: joblib uses the underlying multiprocessing module. It's probably best to call into multiprocessing directly for this.

Answer (score 10):

Can't figure out how to add to the code or reply to the message but here's support for jython that you can tack in before you give up:

```
# jython
try:
    from java.lang import Runtime
    runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
    res = runtime.availableProcessors()
    if res > 0:
        return res
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using torch you can do:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp

mp.cpu_count()
```

the mp library in torch has the same interface as the main python one so you can do this too as the commenter mentioned:

```
python -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())"
```

hope this helps! ;) it's always nice to have more than 1 option.

Comment: This answer should NOT be the first answer. Why to use `torch`, a deep learning framework, for a such easy task?

Just run:

```python -c "import multiprocessing; print(multiprocessing.cpu_count())"```

Comment: @EliSimhayev oh I forgot that actually the torch mp module has the same interface so they are the same but will add details ;)  and no it's not the first answer, there are some before me :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you don't have Python 2.6:

```
import commands
n = commands.getoutput("grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is only available on Linux though, and already included [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1006301/35070).

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for printing the number of cores in your system.

**Try this:**

```
import os 
no_of_cores = os.cpu_count()
print(no_of_cores)
```

This should help.

Comment: This solution is already provided in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636145/5320906).  When answering old questions, please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Comment: ok thanks will provide suitable information.