# Is there a way to get processes information of local machine with python?

Tags: python, cpu, process

I want something that will receive me the processes details, like I receive with 'ps' command in linux,

get 2 basically types- CPU usage and Memory Used.

today to get this I am using uncomfortable way:

```
subprocess.check_output(["ps", "aux"])
```

........

and parse the output of this..

any idea or solution way is acceptable!

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842448/getting-processor-information-in-python

Comment: @Trevor, that question is about **processor** information, but this question is about **process** info

Comment: @TJD Whoops, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Trevor - as TJD says, I mean to processes and not processor, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use **[psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)**

Typical usage and example for a process:

```
psUtilInfo - psutil.Process(pid)
cpuPercentage = int(psUtilInfo.get_cpu_percent())
memoryInfo, _vms =psUtilInfo.get_memory_info()
```

To get all processes

```
psutil.get_pid_list()
```

I think you can also get more information like this from this module.

Comment: Good one! can you give me please example how to iterate all the available processes?

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) package.  I don't know of a way using strictly the stdlib.