# How to get the processor name in Python?

Tags: python, windows

Using the platform module in Python on my Windows laptop, I get the following output

```
import platform
platform.processor()
```

`'Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel`'

If I look at the Windows System Information, however, I am told that my processor is an Intel Core i5-3317U CPU at 1.70Ghz.  How can I get Python to return processor information in this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some com interface through [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) you can:

```
def get_cpu_type():
    from win32com.client import GetObject
    root_winmgmts = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
    cpus = root_winmgmts.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
    return cpus[0].Name
```

The result on my machine:

> Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           W3550  @ 3.07GHz

You can also get all sorts of info on the CPUs this way. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If you are ok with using libraries (copied answer from [Getting processor information in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842448/getting-processor-information-in-python/49719234#49719234))

> you can use [`cpuinfo`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-cpuinfo).
>
> Install as `pip install py-cpuinfo`
>
> Use from the commandline: `python -m cpuinfo`
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> import cpuinfo
> cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand_raw']
> ```

Comment: For me, the returned dict has no `brand` key, only `brand_raw` but it works equally well for me.

Comment: @mxmlnkn : thanks, it seems to have changed indeed