# Python - Core Speed

Tags: python, cpu, cpu-speed, cpu-cores

I'm trying to find out where this value is stored in both **windows** and **osx**, in order to do some calculations to make a better task distribution.

Core speed **in Hz**

Thanks in advance.

Using the *platform.process()* command only returns the name not the speed

I only managed to get it trough this:

```
import subprocess  
info=subprocess.check_output(["wmic","cpu","get", "name"])  
print info.split('@')[1].split(' ')[1]
```

But for the moment i have no way to tell if it will always return the same result in every machine (no access to other computers right now)

Comment: If you have a vague idea, share your code or do not ask for these first two points. It is always recommended to show what you have already tried before posting here.

Comment: i did it some years ago, i would have to search trough all my scripts to find where and how

Comment: Not a duplicate. The question linked is asking specifically about processor name, not speed. Upvote in defiance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Machine ID

There is currently no cross platform python way of getting a Machine ID, however this has been asked before:
[Get a unique computer ID in Python on windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461141/get-a-unique-computer-id-in-python-on-windows-and-linux)

if you just want the machine name use `platform.node()`

### Number of cores

The `multiprocessing` module contains the `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` method

### Cores speed in Hz

There is currently no cross platform python way of getting cpu frequency, however this has been asked before: [Getting processor information in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842448/getting-processor-information-in-python)

Comment: thanks Atsch, yet about the speed, the _platform.processor()_ only returns the name not the speed

Comment: @Nightmareslnd yes, indeed. IIRC one of the lower answers shows you how to parse the system information for the frequency though.