# View actual CPU clock speed Python

Tags: python

So, I have an overclocked CPU, and I would like to see the actual CPU clock speed (in my case 5.1GHz) in windows.
In linux it's pretty easy `os.system(lscpu | grep "MHz")`, but when I try it in windows, with `wmic` I only get the base clock speed, which, in my case is 3.6GHz.
Is there an effective way to do this in python, with a library, a terminal command or other ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Core Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672533/python-core-speed)

Comment: The linux solution is basically using system commands, not Python itself, to get the value. Asking this as a OS specific question rather than a Python specific question seems more appropriate.

Comment: I can't actually test it right now, but there seems to be a WMI module, https://pypi.org/project/WMI/, and it may or may not be used for re-creating https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802420/unable-to-get-current-cpu-frequency-in-powershell-or-python in Python.