# python script to find if the cpuspeed is the same

Tags: python

I need to find if the cpu speed is unique using python.
Need the equivalent of the below script in python:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | uniq | wc -l
```

This is finding the speed of cpu and check if they are all unique.
Returns 1 if unique, more than 1 if not unique.

Any other suggestions to check the same are also invited.

Comment: what do you mean by *unique*? Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842448/getting-processor-information-in-python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read `/proc/cpuinfo` and process the input with Python:

```
with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as f:
    speeds = [line.strip().split(': ')[1] for line in f if line.startswith('cpu MHz')]
    print(len(set(speeds)))
```

This will print the number of unique cpu speeds: `1` in the unlikely event that all speeds are the same, otherwise > 1.

As a function that returns a `bool`:

```
def same_speed():
    with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as f:
        return len(set(line.strip().split(': ')[1] for line in f if line.startswith('cpu MHz'))) == 1
```