# How to get model name of cpu in windows using python

Tags: python

is there anyway to get model name of cpu using python ?

I have code which gives model name in Linux but i want model name in windows.

**code:**

```
with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as f:
    for line in f:
       # Ignore the blank line separating the information between
       # details about two processing units
       if line.strip():
           if line.rstrip('\n').startswith('model name'):
               model_name = line.rstrip('\n').split(':')[1]
               model=model_name
               model=model.strip()
               break
print(model)
```

please help me ?

Comment: both are same ? @Pavel

Comment: To get cpu model name, write a line of python code to execute this command: WMIC CSPRODUCT GET NAME

Answer (score 0):

The [platform.processor()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.processor) function returns the processor name as a string.

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.processor()
'Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel'
```

Comment: Same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842448/getting-processor-information-in-python

Comment: (not the downvoter, but) If you're repeating an answer from an identical question, what you should instead do is flag the question as a duplicate so it can be closed, rather than answer it.

Comment: Sorry, new on this