# Get the processor type using python for Apple M1 processor gives me an Intel processor

Tags: python, processor, platform, apple-m1

I have the new MacBook Pro with M1 processor which is ARM based processor, when I try to get the processor type of my device using python programming language it tells me this is an Intel processor 'i386' !! how could that happen.

Code:

```
*import platform

platform.processor()
Out[4]: 'i386'*
```

Comment: Its Python 3.8 , Spyder IDE

Comment: Yep, looks like it does the same here as it does for NetBSD. https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the conclusion:

**Yes**,  it's correct under the Python3 version <= **3.9.1**, you can check this info thourgh the [isapplesiliconready.com](https://isapplesiliconready.com/zh/app/Python), it shown the Python was supported the m1 chip when it version greater than 3.9.1. As you were said, you're using `Spyder IDE` which may controlled by the `Anaconda`, it doesn't support m1 chip so far.

---

So, **Why**?

The reason is `Rosetta`, follow the [official link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861), it show you how the old app running under m1 chip, basicial you just need to know is most of the old apps was running in `compatibility mode` unless the developer release the version which was sepcial written or optimized for m1 chip. So what was the `Rosstta` done? It just pseudo you were using `Intel chip` when you need to run an old app, thus, the result is same whit `Intel chip`.

---

**How** to solve this case?

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719234), although the function name was changed, but it still can be used to solve this case, here is the code.

```py
import cpuinfo

# Just get the manufacturer of the processors

manufacturer = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info().get('brand_raw')
# 'Apple M1 Pro'

arch = 'arm' if 'm1' in manufacturer.lower() else 'x86_64'

# You can get all the info through the `get_cpu_info_json()`, like below.

>>> cpuinfo.get_cpu_info_json()

{
  "python_version": "3.9.7.final.0 (64 bit)",
  "cpuinfo_version": [
    8,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "cpuinfo_version_string": "8.0.0",
  "arch": "X86_64",
  "bits": 64,
  "count": 10,
  "arch_string_raw": "x86_64",
  "brand_raw": "Apple M1 Pro",
  "hz_actual_friendly": "2.4000 GHz",
  "hz_actual": [
    2400000000,
    0
  ],
  "family": 6,
  "flags": [
    "acpi",
    "aes",
    "apic",
    "clflush",
    "clfsh",
    "cmov",
    "cx16",
    "cx8",
    "de",
    "ds",
    "dscpl",
    "dtes64",
    "dtse64",
    "est",
    "fpu",
    "fxsr",
    "htt",
    "lahf_lm",
    "mca",
    "mce",
    "mmx",
    "mon",
    "monitor",
    "msr",
    "mtrr",
    "pae",
    "pat",
    "pbe",
    "pclmulqdq",
    "pdcm",
    "pge",
    "pni",
    "popcnt",
    "pse",
    "pse36",
    "seglim64",
    "sep",
    "ss",
    "sse",
    "sse2",
    "sse3",
    "sse4.1",
    "sse4.2",
    "sse4_1",
    "sse4_2",
    "ssse3",
    "tm",
    "tm2",
    "tpr",
    "tsc",
    "vme",
    "vmx"
  ],
  "vendor_id_raw": "GenuineIntel",
  "hz_advertised_friendly": "2.5000 GHz",
  "hz_advertised": [
    2500000000,
    0
  ],
  "l2_cache_size": 65536,
  "l2_cache_line_size": 8192,
  "l2_cache_associativity": 8,
  "model": 44
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happens to me but only under spyder. if I do it under command line python3, I get the correct result!