# Modify CPU-intensive function to parallel function

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a function where I'm reading lines from stdin and using `itertools.groupby` to group lines and then do some processing. My code looks like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def func(lines):
    for key, group in groupby(lines, key=itemgetter(0)):
        lst = list(group)
        results = my_cpu_intensive_function(lst)

        # send results to stdout for further processing
        print(results)

def main():
    # a generator holding lists of data
    lines = (line.strip().split('\t') for line in sys.stdin)
    func(lines)
```

Everything works how I want it too, however, my `my_cpu_intensive_function()` is very CPU-intensive. How can I parallelize this function to speed up my code? I was looking at `multiprocessing.Pool()`, but I couldn't figure out how to use it or if it was the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing is definitely a good module to use. I haven't used `Pool` personally (I usually just spawn processes with `Process()` ), but it looks pretty easy in the documentation.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Just make a list of your inputs to the worker processes, and use `pool.map()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from multiprocessing import pool

def func(lines):
    groups = []
    for key, group in groupby(lines, key=itemgetter(0)):
        groups.append( list(group) )

    pool = Pool(processes=len(groups))

    results_lst = pool.map( my_cpu_intensive_function, groups )

    # send results to stdout for further processing
    print(results)

def main():
    # a generator holding lists of data
    lines = (line.strip().split('\t') for line in sys.stdin)
    func(lines)
```

Though if you have a lot of groups, you might want to be careful with how many subprocesses you are spawning. Perhaps replacing `len(groups)` by `max( len(groups), 16)` or so is a good idea. You can find out a good value to max out at via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, appending each group into a list of groups won't work for me. I'm working with a lot of lines and I wont be able to hold all that data in memory. What I'd like is some way to split the groups and call `my_cpu_intensive_function` for each group. Make sense?

Comment: Ahh - I see. That shouldn't be too hard with Process(). I can post an example with that if I have a few minutes later today!

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out.