# TypeError:unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, operands, lammps

I want to convert pmma85compositedata.initeq to a acceptable data file for lammps but I face with this error:

```
import lmpsdata, copy
data=lmpsdata.Lmpsdata('pmma85compositedata.initeq','full')
polymer=lmpsdata.molecules(data,1,19,'atom') #'atom
nanoparticle=lmpsdata.molecules(data,20,20,'atom')
surface=lmpsdata.particlesurface(nanoparticle[0], 1.94, 8,'full')
```

Error:

```
polymer=lmpsdata.molecules(data,1,19,'atom') #'atom
File "/home/marham/...../lmpsdata.py", line 1193, in molecules
p=Pool(processors)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 159, in __init__
self._repopulate_pool()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 214, in        _repopulate_pool
for i in range(self._processes - len(self._pool)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/lammps/lammps/blob/4bd3fe89c88d2f53968d282d3538cd59b8c0a95f/tools/polybond/lmpsdata.py#L1186-L1200) for the `lmpsdata.molecules()` function, you are missing a parameter: the number of processors in the pool. Try:

```
polymer = lmpsdata.molecules(data, 1, 19, 8, 'atom')
nanoparticle = lmpsdata.molecules(data, 20, 20, 8, 'atom')
```

...or replace `8` with [however many processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python) you have at your disposal.