# How many CPUs does a docker container use?

Tags: docker

Lets say I am running a [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) service inside a docker container spawning multiple processes, would docker use all/multiple cores/CPUs of the host or just one?

Comment: As many CPUs as the cgroup it's in is allowed to use. Which, by default, isn't limited. See `--cpuset-cpus` if you wanted to change that.

Comment: (A docker container is just a bunch of private namespaces -- since it isn't emulating CPUs, it would need to go out of its way to impose any restrictions on them; Linux kernels provide facilities to *allow* such going-out-of-one's-way, but that's still something that needs to actually be explicitly performed).

Comment: How about Docker Toolbox on Windows, which uses VirtualBox?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

As Charles mentions, by default all can be used, or you can limit it per container using the `--cpuset-cpus` parameter.

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-2" myapp:latest
```

That would restrict the container to 3 CPU's (0, 1, and 2). See the [docker run docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint) for more details.

---

The preferred way to limit CPU usage of containers is with a fractional limit on CPUs:

```
docker run --cpus 2.5 myapp:latest
```

That would limit your container to 2.5 cores on the host.

---

Lastly, if you run docker inside of a VM, including Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, and docker-machine, those VM's will have a CPU limit separate from your laptop itself. Docker runs inside of that VM and will use all the resources given to the VM itself. E.g. with Docker for Mac you have the following menu:

[image: Docker for Mac Advanced settings]

Comment: Would two docker containers running on the same VM with 2 CPUs affect performance if they are both spawning processes? So both spawns two processes for a total of four when there is only 2 CPUs on the VM?

Comment: @cocoPuffs unless you specify CPU limits, it's the same as if you run those processes outside of a container on the same host. Adding CPU limits to each container can prevent processes in one container from using all of the CPU resources for itself.

Comment: can you run multiple containers on single cpu?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer yes, same as running multiple processes on one CPU.

Comment: BTW, why is the "preferred" way to limit CPU usage of containers with a "fractional" limit? Are you just demonstrating that you can use fractions, or is there actually an advantage to them over integer CPU counts?

Comment: @magnus it's not a count of CPUs, but specifying specific cores, which no other process running on the host is limited to by default. Therefore you'll never get the full core, and the kernel can't schedule your process on another idle core.

Comment: Note: `--cpus` is based off of cores, not threads. So if you have 6 core, 12 threads, to limit it to 7 threads you would use `--cpus=7` (or `--cpus 7`)

Answer (score 19):

Maybe your host VM has only one core by default. Therefore you should increase your VM **cpu-count** first and then use ***--cpuset-cpus*** option to increase your docker cores. You can remove docker default VM using the following command then you can create another VM with optional **cpu-count** and **memory** size.:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count=8 --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-disk-size=50000 default
```

After this step you can specify number of cores before running your image. this command will use 4 cores of total 8 cores.

```
docker run -it --cpuset-cpus="0-3" your_image_name
```

Then you can check number of available core in your image using this command:

```
nproc
```