# How to make Docker use all CPU cores?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get Docker to use all the available CPU cores on my hardware (4). Docker can only see one CPU core:

```
$ docker run --cpuset-cpus="0-3" -ti ubuntu bash
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Requested CPUs are not available - requested 0-3, available: 0.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

**How do I make Docker use all available cores?**

The Docker documentation claims that setting the cpus flag to 0.000 forces Docker to use all available cores, but this doesn't work for me:

```
$ docker run --cpus=0.000  -ti ubuntu bash
root@36855ab28928:/# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x19
cpu MHz         : 2890.620
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm pti fsgsbase
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf
bogomips        : 5781.24
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

```
$ docker run --cpus=0.000 -ti ubuntu bash
root@6c1d6934a0fe:/# lscpu | head -n 10
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
root@6c1d6934a0fe:/#
```

I'm using Docker Quickstart Terminal to get the command prompt that you see above.

My physical hardware is a Windows 10 laptop. Using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows:

```
$ lscpu | head -n 10
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
```

I have Oracle VM Virtualbox installed, but I don't know if that has anything to do with this. I'm a Docker total novice. Other answers on Stack Overflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871540/how-many-cpus-does-a-docker-container-use)) claim that by default all CPUs are available, and have found no information online to the contrary. I've scoured the Docker documentation and found nothing that would indicate that I need to do something special to unlock the other CPU cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most probably due to your installation of Docker. Docker by default can use all system resources. Toolbox installation uses VM from Virtualbox. You should increase the resources of the VM on Virtualbox.

If you are using Windows 10, you should not use Docker Toolbox due to it's only for legacy OS (Win 7). You should use Docker CE.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's very likely indeed that the problem is due to my installation of Docker. I'm a novice, and it's probably that I messed up somewhere with the installation. I'm running on a laptop, not a server. I don't know if that makes a difference. Can you point me to a recipe for setting up Docker CE, preferably one that is known to work on a laptop running Windows 10? I could Google, but I'd value a recommendation from an expert.

Comment: You can download it from [here](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows). Make virtualization features on your laptop's BIOS is enabled.  Also, don't forget to put answered :).

Comment: Thanks! But... how do I enable virtualisation features on my laptop's BIOS? I haven't the foggiest idea.

Comment: I don't think you will have any issues since that you already have VM working on your laptop. Just try giving it a shot. If Docker gives an error related to this, you can check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1382472/how-do-i-find-and-enable-the-virtualization-setting-on-windows-10).