# Why does docker have more cpus available than the limit I set?

Tags: docker

I'm running my container with

```sh
docker run --rm -it --cpus=1 --memory "8G" -v "$pwd":"/code/" 'algolab' bash
```

This means according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint) that the container will only use one cpu core.

> `--cpus=0.000`    Number of CPUs.
> Number is a fractional number. 0.000 means no limit.

But when I run `nproc` inside the container, it tells me it sees `8` cores - the same number as on my host.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871814/2550406) supports that claim. But it also mentions `--cpuset-cpus="0-2"`. When I use that, in addition to `--cpus=1`, I get the result `3` from `nproc`.

**Why is docker ignoring `--cpus=1`?**
And how do I make it stop ignoring it?

---

For now, I can use `--cpuset-cpus="0"`, but I don't understand why that's necessary.

---

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--cpus` option sets a quota on the CPU usage - this does not restrict which CPUs can be used nor how many at a time; this restricts the total slice of time they can be running on your CPU. So if you pass `--cpus 1` on a machine with 8 cores, the container will be limited to running on 1/8th of your CPU time. This is covered on [a different section of the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-period-constraint).

Comment: This may not be wholly true. In my case the host machine is a 16 core machine running CentOS 7, docker version: `20.10.18`. On setting `--cpus=0.06` alone (1/16 of the cores), the container still got access to all 16 cores. But, when I set `--cpus=0.06 --cpuset-cpus="1"`, then my container got 1 cpu as expected. But, I am not sure of the implication of forcefully assigning only cpu=1 to the container. I will get to know more as I run my application on it.

Comment: I don't get what's your point - the answer is regarding just `--cpus`, and the question already mentioned `--cpuset-cpus`. Also, `--cpus=0.06` does not mean "1/16 of the cores", it means "a time share of at most 1/16 of a single core".