# CPU Benchmark (SPEC2006) in Container (How to control number of CPU?)

Tags: linux, cpu, benchmarking, linux-containers

I wanna run SPEC2006 benchmark in Container.

So I installed SPEC2006 and I checked it is running well.
I want to create a container with 1, 2, 4, 8 CPUs and run benchmarks in each environment.

But I setup the CPU number as 2 but I checked 8 CPU is working same the time(my local host has 8 cpus)  when SPEC2006 is running.

So I wanna ask you guys to how to control number of CPUS of Container ?

Comment: Possibly related: [How many CPUs does a docker container use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37871540) if you're using docker to manage the container, and maybe even without docker, IDK.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in the official guide](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/), in order to limit a container to a specific number a CPU, you should use the parameter `--cpuset-cpus`.

Tell me if it works for you too.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for reply as you said, there is cpu limitation options. But when I run the SPEC benchmark in container after set cpu limitation option as 2, all cpus are working (in my case 8 cpus working). 8 cpu is working and  usage is just 25%. The total usage is 200%, equivalent to the total usage of two CPUs. But I want to know how to operate only two CPUs, not eight CPUs. ;)