# multiprocessing.cpu_count returning wrong number of cores

Tags: python

I try to use the following code to decide the number of cores of my laptop:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```

The result is 8, but when I open the system report, I can see that I have only 1 CPU with 4 cores.

What's wrong with `cpu_count()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 4 physical cores, but 8 logical processors. For example, you may have a processor with [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

From SuperUser: [Difference Between Cores and Processors](https://superuser.com/questions/168809/difference-between-cores-and-processors)

Comment: What function should I call to get the number of physical cores?

Comment: From this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14840102/431033: `psutil` has a `cpu_count` function with this option.

Answer (score 1):

What CPU do you have, it might be counting the Physical cores + virtual cores.