# Find the number of CPUs in tox.ini

Tags: python, tox

I know how to find the [number of CPUs using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006301/232794), but how do I do that within a tox.ini file?

What I want is something akin to this:

```
commands =
  py.test --cov=ook -n ${number_of_cpu_I_can_use}
```