# Assigning a thread to specific CPU core

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, cpu-usage

AFAIK, it is possible to assign a thread to a CPU core in Linux. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854709/can-i-programmatically-pick-and-choose-which-core-of-a-multi-core-cpu-my-thread-s)). But, my question is can I achieve this functionality using **boost** and if it is possible, then how? Please, also not that OS can decide which is better for me, but assume that I want to control this behavior in my design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost is meant to be a *cross platform library* while the question you linked to points toward a *OS specific implementation* which to my knowledge is the only way to do what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows OS you can use [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call for this. I don't see how boost fits in what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The topic is called "thread affinity", you could find the response by searching for this plus your exact operating system version.