# Threading With Multiple Cores C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I don't know how to thread in C++ and I would not just wan't to know that but is there a way i can force a thread onto a different core? Also how would I find out how many cores the user has?

Comment: You cannot force a thread to run in *parallel* in standard C++. That is at the environment's underlying thread scheduler (usually in the kernel). All you are guaranteed is *concurrency*.

Comment: ... but, anyways, you should try using the [new `thread` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) in C++11.

Comment: These are really three questions. The most specific one, about choosing the core, has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886886/assigning-a-thread-to-specific-cpu-core).

Answer (score 4):

Binding thread to the arbitrary CPU is called setting affinity. It's platform-dependent operation.

For windows: [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For pthreads: `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np(3)` and `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)`

For Boost you can use `native_handle()` to get platform-specific thread handle to use them with functions above.

Comment: ... right; C++11 equivalent would be to access the similar [`thread::native_handle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). Though it should be warned that this is non-standard.

Comment: Note that the `native_handle` function is standard. What you *get* from it is what is "non-standard".