# How to Assign thread to a particular core

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, cpu-cores

This question is similar to [Assigning a thread to specific CPU core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886886/assigning-a-thread-to-specific-cpu-core)

However, it doesn't go into much details. Can we assign thread to a particular core in Java env. I chatted with technology department head of in a buy side firm and came to know that creating x worker threads and assigning them to x cores (dedicated core for each worker thread) provides best latency in trading applications.
I wonder how can we do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238272/java-thread-affinity probably should answer your question.

Comment: @user486075: Indeed. Voting to close as a duplicate. Thanks for the link.