# How to prevent inheriting CPU affinity by child forked process?

Tags: c++, linux, fork, affinity, execvp

I have a server process that forks many child processes. The server process has affinity to a CPU core, but I don't want that affinity to be inherited by child process (rather OS should handle where to run these processes). Is there a way to delink parent child processes with respect to cpu affinity?

Comment: If nothing else you could probably de-link the parent process before forking the child, and then re-link it again afterwards...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call [`sched_setaffinity(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) with all bits set in CPU mask after the [`fork(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) and before the [`execve(2)`](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html).