# How to use sched_getaffinity and sched_setaffinity in Linux from C?

Tags: c, linux, process, schedule, affinity

I am trying to:

- Run 16 copies concurrently with processor pinning (2 copies per core)
- Run 8 copies concurrently with processor pinning (2 copies per core) and flipping processor core to the furthest core after certain function say function 1 finishes.

The problem I am facing is how to select the farthest processor.

Some friends suggested to use sched_getaffinity and sched_setaffinity but I count not find any good examples.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To use sched_setaffinity to make the current process run on core 7 you do this:

```
cpu_set_t my_set;        /* Define your cpu_set bit mask. */
CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       /* Initialize it all to 0, i.e. no CPUs selected. */
CPU_SET(7, &my_set);     /* set the bit that represents core 7. */
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set); /* Set affinity of tihs process to */
                                                  /* the defined mask, i.e. only 7. */
```

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity & http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/CPU-Affinity.html for more info.

Comment: What should we do to set several cores instead of just one? call CPU_SET in a for loop?

Answer (score 19):

**Minimal runnable example**

In this example, we get the affinity, modify it, and check if it has taken effect with [`sched_getcpu()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574301/895245).

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_affinity() {
    cpu_set_t mask;
    long nproc, i;

    if (sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1) {
        perror("sched_getaffinity");
        assert(false);
    }
    nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
    printf("sched_getaffinity = ");
    for (i = 0; i < nproc; i++) {
        printf("%d ", CPU_ISSET(i, &mask));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    cpu_set_t mask;

    print_affinity();
    printf("sched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(0, &mask);
    if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1) {
        perror("sched_setaffinity");
        assert(false);
    }
    print_affinity();
    /* TODO is it guaranteed to have taken effect already? Always worked on my tests. */
    printf("sched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/4aff114c4c654014a97ef23b1513dda5409e79f3/userland/linux/sched_getaffinity.c).

Compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

Sample output:

```
sched_getaffinity = 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
sched_getcpu = 9
sched_getaffinity = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 0
```

Which means that:

- initially, all of my 16 cores were enabled, and the process was randomly running on core 9 (the 10th one)
- after we set the affinity to only the first core, the process was moved necessarily to core 0 (the first one)

It is also fun to run this program through `taskset`:

```
taskset -c 1,3 ./a.out
```

Which gives output of form:

```
sched_getaffinity = 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 2
sched_getaffinity = 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sched_getcpu = 0
```

and so we see that it limited the affinity from the start.

This works because the affinity is inherited by child processes, which `taskset` is forking: [How to prevent inheriting CPU affinity by child forked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336191/how-to-prevent-inheriting-cpu-affinity-by-child-forked-process)

`nproc` respects `sched_getaffinity` by default as shown at: [How to find out the number of CPUs using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python/55423170#55423170)

**Python: `os.sched_getaffinity` and `os.sched_setaffinity`**

See: [How to find out the number of CPUs using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006289/how-to-find-out-the-number-of-cpus-using-python/55423170#55423170)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: How can we use more  than 1 cpu? how to specify that in the mask?

Comment: Use CPU_SET(0, &mask); then CPU_SET(1,&mask), etc.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use CPU_SETSIZE as cpusetsize parameter for sched_[set|get]affinity. The names are misleading but this is wrong.
The macro CPU_SETSIZE is (quoting man 3 cpu_set) "a value one greater than the maximum CPU number that can be stored in cpu_set_t."
You have to use

```
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set);
```

instead.