# Using the C programming language, what is the best way to make a multicore RedHat Linux processor, use only one core in a test application?

Tags: c

Using the `C` programming language, what is the best way to make a multicore Red Hat Linux processor, use only one core in a test application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [Linux system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280909/cpu-affinity) specifically for this purpose called `sched_setaffinity`

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490756/how-to-use-sched-getaffinity2-and-sched-setaffinity2-please-give-code-samp), to run on CPU 0:

```
#include <sched.h>
int main(void)
{
    cpu_set_t  mask;
    CPU_ZERO(&mask);
    CPU_SET(0, &mask);
    result = sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(mask), &mask);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Gearoid Murphy, Thank you for your answer. I will test it one hour and award you one Stack Overflow point and aceept your  answer.

Comment: Note: `int main(void)`