# Assign CPU cores programmatically from C/C++ in CentOS 7 and GCC 5.2

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance

I would like to programmatically isolate my process to run on a core different from everything else (including the OS), to reduce context switching. I found this similar question:

[Whole one core dedicated to single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process)

And the accepted answer dated 2011:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585364/997112

mentions:

> The alternative method is to use cpusets which is way more elegant and
>   dynamic but suffers from some weaknesses at this point in time (no
>   migration of timers for example) which makes me recommend the old,
>   crude but effective isolcpus parameter.
>
> Note that work is currently being done by the Linux community to
>   address all these issues and more to give even better isolation.

Has there been any update? Is it possible to emulate isolcpus from a Linux C API function?

My C++ environment is CentOS 7 and GCC 5.2

Comment: This is something that's implementation specific. There's nothing in the C++ standard for this. Therefore, at the very least, you need to specify which C++ implementation you are using.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not sure what you mean by which C++ implementation? I assumed there would be Linux C API calls. Did you mean which version of Linux?

Comment: @user997112 Sam's comment is about how the language C++ makes no mention of this so there is no generic portable answer that will be true for all C++ developers. A C++ implementation is a specific implementation of the language, a set of tools (compiler, linker, standard library implementation, etc.) and an environment that allows a developer to convert C++ code into an executable form. You need to specify what implementation you are using for a reasonable answer (ex. gcc version x.y on Linux distro such-and-such). In this case, the platform you are using is very important.

Comment: I have just added my C++ environment info to the question. Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: For Linux, the appropriate system call [appears to be sched_setaffinity(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/sched_setaffinity.2.html). I don't have specific knowledge of it, to write a complete answer, but that's where you want to look further.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks but I think that only solves half the problem (the easier half). The part which is trickier is scheduling all other processes to not run on your core (what isolcpus does).

Comment: Well, then you have the answer: use usolcpus boot option, and use the reserved CPUs for your own threads. As the man page explains, in the "NOTES" section, there is no other option: either use isolcpus, or manually isolate every process on the system.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to achieve is known as *CPU affinity*. This is usually a task done at sysadmin stage and not at programming, in an enterprise environment a programme will deliver binaries and the sysadmin group may or may not decide to give certain binaries a certain affinity.

Usually this is done with the `taskset` command, see [Realtime Reference Guide: Affinity](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Affinity.html).

This command will run `my-c-app` on core 4 exclusively

```
taskset -c 4 /bin/my-c-app
```

If you want to do it inside the code of your C program regardless of what I mentioned, see [Section 6.2. Using the sched_getaffinity() system call to set processor affinity](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/sect-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Affinity-Using_the_sched_getaffinity_system_call_to_set_processor_affinity.html) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11271253) to the thread [How to use sched_getaffinity and sched_setaffinity in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490756/how-to-use-sched-getaffinity-and-sched-setaffinity-in-linux-from-c).

A very short example:

```
cpu_set_t my_set;        /* Define your cpu_set bit mask. */
CPU_ZERO(&my_set);       /* Initialize it all to 0, i.e. no CPUs selected. */
CPU_SET(7, &my_set);     /* set the bit that represents core 7. */
sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &my_set); /* Set affinity of tihs process to */
                                                  /* the defined mask, i.e. only 7. */
```

Comment: Hi, the question is more about preventing other processes running on the core I have reserved.

Comment: @user997112 There's not really any nice option for doing so except iterate through all existing processes and change their affinity using sched_setaffinity()  to be anything except the core you want to run on. (This applies to user space proceses only, there is no way to prevent the kernel from utilizing a core)

Answer (score 0):

Using the linux API sched_setaffinity() to set the calling processes's processor affinity on a SMP system would partially achieve your requirement.

To not allow any other processes from being scheduled on the reserved CPU, you need to achieve it programmatically by using lock-less and no-sleep implementations. This totally blocks any other process/thread from being context-switched on the reserved CPU.